# Bin - deploying a MySQL Entity Framework Provider - based application in WPF?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework

I need to deploy a normal WPF application with the MySQL EF provider on a machine that **don't have** the MySQL Connector installed but obviously i got a sort of "Provider not found" exception.

I copied the references data in the executable directory (MySQL.Data.Entity.dll, MySQL.Data.dll, etc..)

What i need to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should reference in your Code (via Nuget) MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entities. Then it should work

Comment: I installed the connector via the MySQL installer, what i need to do exactly with nuget? Can you give me some steps?

Comment: 1. Check if nuget ist installed : Tools ->NuGet-Packet-Manager should be listed.

Comment: 2. If not install Nuget Packet Manager (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)

Comment: 3. Right click on your solution -> Nuget-Packages for Solution

Comment: 4. Click on Online and Search for MySQL

Comment: 5. Click on Install for MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entites